# Checkboxes toggling QPushbutton functions (append strings + show custom icons)

Tags: c++, qt

I made an app to practice c++ and qt (beginner level)

**Looks like this:** *(mahjong theme!)*
[image]

Atm, all it does is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEVnm.jpg

Pretty simple, but I'd like to add some features.

Problem is, I did not think adding them would be that difficult (at least for me).

**"Player 1" checkbox**

- Only by ticking the "Player 1" checkbox should the action seen in the gif be allowed. (right now it is always allowed; no need to tick the box)
- While that box is ticked, it should also add each tiles icon's to the "graphicsView" area, as each tiles are clicked, in the same order as seen in the output inside "textEdit box 1".

  (on top of the string append feature of "textEdit box 1", which is already working right now)
- A maximum of 13 tiles should be allowed in "textEdit" box and "graphicsView" area

Like so: [http://imgur.com/SUWHJSK](https://imgur.com/SUWHJSK)

I am saving what the "Wall" checkbox should do for later :)

My code is probably disastrous, sorry about that. <- still very beginner  but here goes:

**.pro file:**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = HandBuilder_Mahjong
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
    tiles.qrc
```

**mainwindow.h:**

```
private slots:
    void addTextToLabel();
    void addTextToLabel2();
    void addTextToLabel3();
    void addTextToLabel4();
    void addTextToLabel5();
    void addTextToLabel6();
    void addTextToLabel7();
    void addTextToLabel8();
    void addTextToLabel9();
    void addTextToLabel10();
    void addTextToLabel11();
    void addTextToLabel12();
    void addTextToLabel13();
    void addTextToLabel14();
    void addTextToLabel15();
    void addTextToLabel16();
    void addTextToLabel17();
    void addTextToLabel18();
    void addTextToLabel19();
    void addTextToLabel20();
    void addTextToLabel21();
    void addTextToLabel22();
    void addTextToLabel23();
    void addTextToLabel24();
    void addTextToLabel25();
    void addTextToLabel26();
    void addTextToLabel27();

    void addTextToLabel28();
    void addTextToLabel29();
    void addTextToLabel30();
    void addTextToLabel31();
    void addTextToLabel32();
    void addTextToLabel33();
    void addTextToLabel34();





private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->Bamboo_1, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel()));
    connect(ui->Bamboo_2, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel2()));
    connect(ui->Bamboo_3, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel3()));
    connect(ui->Bamboo_4, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel4()));
    connect(ui->Bamboo_5, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel5()));
    connect(ui->Bamboo_6, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel6()));
    connect(ui->Bamboo_7, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel7()));
    connect(ui->Bamboo_8, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel8()));
    connect(ui->Bamboo_9, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel9()));

    connect(ui->Man_1, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel10()));
    connect(ui->Man_2, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel11()));
    connect(ui->Man_3, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel12()));
    connect(ui->Man_4, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel13()));
    connect(ui->Man_5, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel14()));
    connect(ui->Man_6, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel15()));
    connect(ui->Man_7, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel16()));
    connect(ui->Man_8, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel17()));
    connect(ui->Man_9, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel18()));

    connect(ui->Pin_1, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel19()));
    connect(ui->Pin_2, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel20()));
    connect(ui->Pin_3, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel21()));
    connect(ui->Pin_4, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel22()));
    connect(ui->Pin_5, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel23()));
    connect(ui->Pin_6, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel24()));
    connect(ui->Pin_7, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel25()));
    connect(ui->Pin_8, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel26()));
    connect(ui->Pin_9, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel27()));

    connect(ui->Wind_East, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel28()));
    connect(ui->Wind_North, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel29()));
    connect(ui->Wind_South, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel30()));
    connect(ui->Wind_West, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel31()));
    connect(ui->Dragon_Red, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel32()));
    connect(ui->Dragon_Green, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel33()));
    connect(ui->Dragon_White, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(addTextToLabel34()));


}



//Bamboo tiles

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";b1");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel2()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";b2");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel3()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";b3");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel4()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";b4");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel5()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";b5");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel6()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";b6");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel7()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";b7");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel8()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";b8");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel9()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";b9");
}

//Man tiles

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel10()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";n1");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel11()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";n2");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel12()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";n3");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel13()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";n4");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel14()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";n5");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel15()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";n6");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel16()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";n7");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel17()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";n8");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel18()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";n9");
}


// Pin tiles
void MainWindow::addTextToLabel19()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";p1");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel20()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";p2");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel21()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";p3");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel22()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";p4");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel23()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";p5");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel24()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";p6");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel25()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";p7");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel26()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";p8");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel27()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";p9");
}



//Wind tiles
void MainWindow::addTextToLabel28()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";e");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel29()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";n");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel30()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";s");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel31()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";w");
}




//Dragon tiles
void MainWindow::addTextToLabel32()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";rd");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel33()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";gd");
}

void MainWindow::addTextToLabel34()
{
    ui->textEdit->setText(ui->textEdit->toPlainText() + ";wd");
}



MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I'd really love and appreciate some help, even if it's not for all the stuff in I described.

(hopefully I am not asking too much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't see any signal/slot connection for your checkbox so it just does the default, that is checked and unchecked state. If you want to link your checkbox to the textedit, consider

```
connect(ui->player1_checkbox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(toggleTextEdit()));
```

And toggleTextEdit() could be

```
void MainWindow::toggleTextEdit()
        {
         if(ui->player1_checkbox->isChecked())
             ui->textEdit->setEnabled(true);
         else
             ui->textEdit->setEnabled(false);
        }
```

And for the graphicsview, you may have to create an array of size 13 and update the array anytime you change the button under mouse focus, the array content updates in a manner similar to

```
array[counter%13] = currentButtonNumber;
counter = counter+1;
```

You can then update your graphicsview with icons corresponding to the array elements. The variable, counter, is just to keep track of the buttons clicked and update the array accordingly, starting at 0 for every 13th click.
    Hope this works.

Comment: This is helping. I am gonna give it a try and then take a look at the graphic view update.